# cannot print df.shape, and I read it in dataframe format from pandas

Tags: python, pandas, xpath, webdriver

cannot print df.shape, and it read in dataframe format already from pandas, thanks !

```
# -*- coding:UTF-8 -*-

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
display.start()

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.fdmbenzinpriser.dk/searchprices/5/")

lines = [event.get_attribute('outerHTML') for event in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table[@id="sortabletable"]')]

df = pd.read_html(lines[0])
print df.shape

driver.close()
display.stop()
```

Output:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

lines[0] return:

```
[                                           Unnamed: 0   Pris                        Adresse      Tidspunkt
0                                                 NaN   8.99       Odinsvej 2 4100 Ringsted  11 timer 55 m
1                                                 NaN   9.09   Sdr.Havnegade 3 6000 Kolding  14 timer 48 m
2                                                 NaN   9.09    Vestermarksvej 2 6600 Vejen  16 timer 35 m
3                                                 NaN  10.99  Bøsbrovej 92B 8940 Randers SV   21 timer 1 m
```

Comment: What return `lines[0]` ?

Comment: dears, added lines[0] return in the question, thanks !

Comment: Hmm, there is problem you show `df`, not `lines[0]`, right? I try change my answer, but untested

Comment: dears, yes, you're correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need change:

```
df = pd.read_html(lines[0])
```

to:

```
df = pd.read_html(lines[0])[0]
```

And for all data:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_html(line)[0] for line in lines], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, dear !

Answer (score 1):

Pandas read html method doesn't return a dataframe, it returns a list of dataframes:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.read_html.html
You can always check the type of an object in python by using:

```
print(type(obj))
```